# Press enter to submit form if checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form that submits with a button, but I want to also allow to submit by typing the ENTER key if a checkmark has been checked.

I've got the enter part working:

```
<form action="index.php">
  <textarea onkeydown="pressed(event)"></textarea>
</form>
<input type="checkbox" id="enterCheckbox" />

<script>
  function pressed(e) { 
    if ( (window.event ? event.keyCode : e.which) == 13) { document.forms[0].submit() }
  }
</script>
```

Now I want to only run that function if #enterCheckbox has been checked, but I'm having trouble doing it correctly. Any help?

Comment: `if (document.getElementById('enterCheckbox').checked){}`

Comment: Enter triggers the form in `<input>`-type fields. It should not be default for `<textarea>`. If you want that tho, it's better to restyle (CSS) an `<input>` tag to have more height (make it `display:block`). You can then use `$('#formIdName').click(function(){})` and check if certain checkboxes inside `$(this)` are checked (`.attr()`) and then only post it if needed. Use `preventDefault();` to not submit the form by accident.

Comment: @Musa that's what I tried, but it didn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Why isn't your checkbox inside your form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does what you have work as expected other than just adding the extra condition?  If so, you should be able to just add in the extra check with `&&` in your current `if(...)` check.

Something along the lines of `$('#enterCheckbox').attr('checked')` should tell you if the checkbox is checked or not.

Comment: Thanks. Pretty simple solution, that I should of thought of.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
if(document.getElementById(enterCheckbox).checked)) {
    // do all the good stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function should include an extra condition.. something like:

```
<script>
  function pressed(e) { 
    if ( ( (window.event ? event.keyCode : e.which) == 13) AND (document.getElementById('enterCheckbox').checked) ){ document.forms[0].submit() }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if the box is checked, using jQuery:

```
$("#enterCheckbox").is(":checked")
```

So your `<script>` will be:

```
function pressed(e) { 
    if (($("#enterCheckbox").is(":checked")) && ((window.event ? event.keyCode : e.which) == 13)) {
        document.forms[0].submit()
    }
}
```

Comment: `($("#enterCheckbox").is(":checked");)` isn't correctly formatted.

Answer (score 0):

If using jQuery, I suggest using selectors to make life easier. But what you want for checking if `#enterCheckbox` is checked is [`.is(':checked')`](http://api.jquery.com/is/).

**Updated HTML**

```
<form id="myForm" action="index.php">
  <textarea id="myTextarea"></textarea>
</form>
<input type="checkbox" id="enterCheckbox" />
```

**jQuery Implementation**

```
$('#myTextarea').on('keydown', function(e) {
    var key = window.event.keyCode || e.which;

    if($('#enterCheckbox').is(':checked') && key == 13) {
        $('#myForm').submit();
    }
});
```